Windows 11 : legacy driver not working after signing with EV certificate (unless in test signing mode)
We have an old legacy driver, which we use for fan control/temperature, and it pokes some registers of some Pcie bridges to do i2c to control a chip that's hooked up to the bridge's GPIO. Now this driver works fine with normal GlobalSign cert signing on Win10/Win11, but it refuses to work if SecureBoot is turned on.
We were told that we need to sign the driver with ExtendedValidation Cert (EVCert) before SecureBoot will work, hence we bought an EVCert from GlobalSign. Unfortunately when we signed with this, driver doesn't load properly (error 52). If works fine if TESTSIGNING is turn ON. (Driver installs and runs fine with TESTSIGNING ON). This is only an issue when the driver is signed with the EVCert, but not with same driver signed with non-EVCert.  NOTE: SecureBoot is off at this point, so it's not related to SecureBoot.
Question:

Are there special requirements for drivers signed with EV Cert ? i.e. perhaps certain type of drivers (i.e. legacy drivers) will NEVER work with EV Cert ?

I am a new to signing, so and am a little confused. I am reading that I need a EV cert and I need to submit a EVsigned driver to Microsoft. Does this mean that the driver signed by the GlobalSign EVCert was NEVER-supposed-to-work at all (unlike if you sign with non EVCert) ....  until I submit the EVsigned driver to Microsoft for them to sign it ?

Can secure boot work with legacy drivers ? or does it require WDM/WDF drivers.

Haven't done the Microsoft signing yet, but does anybody know if Microsoft signs legacy drivers? Going to be hard to port this legacy driver, because I need to make a non-legacy device driver that has no-hardware, and can map hmm ... "alien" PCIE bridge registers to poke at them to do I2C. Something like a bus driver ??? Is this still doable with a WDM/WDF driver ?
1.Tested with ExtendedValidation Cert/ non ExtendedValidation Cert.
2.Works fine with nonEVCert, or EVCert with TESTSIGNING off.



For modern versions of Windows your driver must be signed by Microsoft; there is, unfortunately, no other way. The EV certificate is used as part of the registration process with Microsoft. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/kernel-mode-code-signing-policy--windows-vista-and-later-
